# Failing to connect and fetch data from my database to the postman

Tags: mongodb, express, postman

I was trying to connect my express with mongodb and hence i ran the mongodb on my terminal and it said waiting for connection but it is still throwing the error             this is the error which i am getting

```
{"message":"Error connecting to database","error":{"reason":{"type":"Unknown","servers":{},"stale":false,"compatible":true,"heartbeatFrequencyMS":10000,"localThresholdMS":15,"setName":null,"maxElectionId":null,"maxSetVersion":null,"commonWireVersion":0,"logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes":null}}
```

i ran the mongodb on my terminal and i was expecting the reply from the database which i have stored in my database but instead it gave me an error msg which i have written in my server.js file

Comment: Check if the MongoDB daemon process mongod is running